# Having trouble updating component state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, nodes

I'm relatively new to ReactJS.

I'm having trouble updating a components state.
When I console log the results of my api fetch, the object is there and not undefined.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
  class Article extends Component {
  state = { post: {} };

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    fetch(`/posts/${id}/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(post => {
        this.setState(post);
        console.log(post);
      });
  }

  renderContent() {
    if (
      Object.entries(this.state.post).length === 0 &&
      this.state.post.constructor === Object
    ) {
      return <p>Blog does not exist sadly</p>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          {Object.keys(this.state.post).map(p => (
            <div
              style={{ maxWidth: "auto", textAlign: "centre" }}
              key={this.state.post[p].title}
            >
              <Header heading={this.state.post[p].title} />
              <div
                style={{ padding: "40px" }}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.post[p].content }}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderContent()}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Article;
```

This is the results of an api fetch:

```
{"_id":"5ce1ae8fc915dc48d13d7c1c","title":"example title","content":"example content"}
```

Express code that returns the results of the MongoDB query:

```
router.get("/posts/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/express", function(
    err,
    client
  ) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var db = client.db("express");
    var id = parseInt(req.params["id"]);
    db.collection("posts")
      .find()
      .sort({ _id: 1 })
      .toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.send(result[id]);
        } else {
          res.status(403);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

This only seems to happen when working with a single result fetch and not when I'm fetching an array of objects.

update:

tried calling console.log(this.state) instead of calling console.log(this.state.post and get this back:

```
{post: {}, _id: "5ce1ae8fc915dc48d13d7c1c", title: "example title", content: "example content"}
```

so seems like it is there but I'm updating the state wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code on codesandbox or stack blitz ?? or give more info its hard to tell from this information.

Comment: Hi, I've added more code. never used code sandbox or stack blitz sorry. Will look into soon.

Comment: Inside the renderContent function you use the map function which is used to handle an array . Instead you can directly access your one post.

Comment: when I console log this.state.post I get an empty object {}. so there's nothing to render.

Comment: That’s because setState is asynchron. Can you try to call console log inside the render function

Comment: You can also use the callback of the console function to log the state: this.setState({post}, () = {console.log(this.state)})

Comment: I tried calling console.log(this.state) instead of calling console.log(this.state.post) and get this back {post: {}, _id: "5ce1ae8fc915dc48d13d7c1c", title: "example title", content: "example content"}... seems like it is there but it has an empty object inside it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double-check if you are using the correct function to set state?

It should be `this.setState({ post })`, not `this.setState(post)`

```
class Article extends Component {
  state = { post: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    fetch(`/posts/${id}/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(post => {
        this.setState({ post }, console.log(this.state.post));
      });
  }

  renderContent() {
    const { post } = this.state
    if (!post) {
      return <p>Blog does not exist sadly</p>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          <div
              style={{ maxWidth: "auto", textAlign: "centre" }}
              key={post.title}
            >
              <Header heading={post.title} />
              <div
                style={{ padding: "40px" }}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }}
              />
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderContent()}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Article;
```

Comment: Hi, does't seem to affect it. I reset my git repo back to a previous version where I was doing something slightly different... seems to work when the api returns [{"_id":"5ce1ae8fc915dc48d13d7c1c","title":"example title","content":"example content"}] instead of the result above. only difference is the square brackets.

Comment: the current way you are setting state will result in the `post` object you are getting from the api being inserted into the state without a key,
i.e. instead of `this.state = {
post: { your fetched post obj }
}`
you will have `this.state = { your fetched post obj }`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment your renderContent function expects an array. You could wrap your single result into an array or directly access the object without using the map() function to solve your problem.